# "There was an error reflecting type" in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, serialization

I need to serialize and exception, i created a Serializable class

```
[Serializable]
public class MessageException : Exception
{
    public string Exception
    { get; set; }
    public MessageException()
    { }
    public MessageException(System.Exception ex) 
    {
        this.Exception = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

and i try to call the class from the following exception when it occur

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageException exception = new MessageException(ex);
            var exSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MessageException));


            var writer = new StringWriter();
            exSerializer.Serialize(writer, exception);
            writer.Close();
            Compair2Files(writer.ToString(), BaseString);
        }
```

it fails on the second row "var exSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MessageException));"

What I m actually trying to do is when I catch the exception I want to serialized it and then store it into a file for my unit test program. 
Would you be able to help me
thanks in advance 
Jp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize an Exception object in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486460/how-to-serialize-an-exception-object-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot serialize exceptions using `XmlSerializer`.
You need to use binary serialization.

The base `Exception` class is already `[Serializale]`, so your class is useless.
It's also wrong; you're ignoring the stack trace.

Comment: ok now my question if i use the binary i need to use stream, can store the stream into a string instead of a file?? mean Stream stream = (something here that will allow me to store it into string) can i use Memorystream ??

Comment: No.  There is no way to serialize an exception to a string.  Instead, you can just call `ex.ToString()`, which will return relevant information.

Comment: You _can_ store the binary data in-memory using `MemoryStream`.

Comment: here my code: now   catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
                BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                bFormatter.Serialize(mStream, ex);

                Compair2Files(mStream.ToString(), BaseString);
            } got a error sayiing SerializationException was unhandled, any idea

Comment: Also, `mStream.ToString()` is meaningless.  There is no way to get a human-readable string.

Comment: Type 'Messages.MessageDefinitionException' in Assembly 'Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: Your custom exception is wrong.  All inherited exceptions must be `[Serializable]`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182350.aspx,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182151.aspx

Comment: well i have a unit test that i compare from expected and actual result this why i store it in a string and compare it with an expected value

Comment: @jpr: Then you'll need to use `ex.ToString()` and not serialization.    I don't think the serialized bytestreams will ever be identical.

Comment: probably it is the best way, cause i was serializing all my objects so this why i try to the same