# How to pass the DTO having property of Type Exception from RIA service

Tags: c#, wcf, ria

I have a DTO as below  -

```
[Serializable()]
Public Class DTO
{
Public Exception ex {get;set;}
}
```

When i pass the object of type DTO from RIA service, on client side I do not see the property ex.
    Please help me with this proble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a sidenote, I do not think of Exceptions should be send directly between clients/ server. Instead I recommend catching them at an appropriate point and re-format the exception information into something more generic before sending it to the receiving side.

As for your actual problem, you might have hit restrictions of the [Serializable] functionality. In MSDN article [Serialization in Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx) it says (highlights by me):

> The default mapping for [Serializable] is different from the one used
>   with XmlSerializer. Here, all fields are included in the mapping,
>   whether public or private, and **properties are never included**.

You might implement your own custom error class that supports serializing.

See SO thread [How to serialize an Exception object in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486460/how-to-serialize-an-exception-object-in-c) for an example.

**[EDIT]**

If that is too much effort, as a quick win, you could try to change the class definition into:

```
[DataContract]
public Class DTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public Exception ex {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens H, I would definitely try the DAtaContract solution. Will this DataContract solution work for the RIA Services?

Comment: @Harshal: Sure, this is 'just' another way of serialization with a few more or less subtle differences to `Serializeable()` . If you are interested in digging deeper into it, you'll find lots of documentation on the net. :-)