# How to propagate an exception across SOAP Web Services?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, exception, asmx

I have a standard ASMX web service.  I want to throw a custom exception and have it be caught on the client side. The only thing that ever comes across is a SoapException. Example:

```
// Server side code
[WebMethod]
public void foo(string bar) {
    throw new CustomException(bar);
}

public class CustomException : Exception {
    ....
}


// Client side code
public void CallFoo() {
    try {
        service.foo()
    }
    catch (CustomException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (SoapException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("IT ALWAYS HITS HERE");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to send through my CustomException exception?  Serialize it somehow perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN:

'[...] any exceptions thrown by an XML Web service method are thrown as a SoapException[...]', [Handling and Throwing Exceptions in XML Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds492xtk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

That said, nothing prevents you from creating an exception wrapper class and serialize it, like @davogones suggested on this post:

[How to serialize an Exception object in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486460/how-to-serialize-an-exception-object-in-c)

Comment: Wrapping SoapException is pointless since that is the only thing that Web Services throw, but your first link proved useful since it allowed me to embed my real exception inside the XML node.

Answer (score 1):

Make your custom exception inherits from SoapException

Comment: This does not work since the only thing Web Services throw are SoapExceptions.