# How to serialize an exception in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

I'm trying to send an exception as a result of a WebJob execution to a response queue:

```
        var message = new BrokeredMessage(exception);
        outputMessages.Add(message);
```

My exception class represents a logical error:

```
public class MyException : Exception{
    public MyException(){}
    public MyException(string message) : base(message){}
    public MyException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner){}
    protected MyException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context){}

    public object MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

However, I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception
>   while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage2Async --->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type
>   'MyException' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the
>   DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you
>   want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type
>   is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.

And when I mark `MyException` with `[DataContract]` I get this:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception
>   while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage2Async --->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type
>   'MyException' cannot be ISerializable and have DataContractAttribute
>   attribute.

Probably because `System.Exception` implements `ISerializable`. How can I fix that?

Comment: "send an exception [...] to a response queue" - does the recipient really need the whole Exception *object*? Or would it be better off with the `.ToString()`, or a status code, or some custom message packet?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't go with a string or enum because I need to pass additional information (`MyProp` in my example) to properly format error messages on UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to serialize your exception with `DataContractSerializer`. Even if you marked your class with `DataContract` successfully, the inner exception can be of any type, thus not compatible.

So you have two options:

1. Serialize your exception with another serializer (and then pass the `Stream` to `BrokeredMessage` constructor). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486460/how-to-serialize-an-exception-object-in-c) for some options.
2. I would argue that sending the exception itself over the wire isn't very clean. I'd rather create a custom message which contains all the information that is important to consumers, and then send this message to Service Bus.